# Why does C++ allow this pointer polymorphism of private parent?

Tags: c++, this, private-inheritance

If I inherit a derived class privately from a base class, I cannot get the polymorphism of the inhritetted class.

But I can get the polymorphism of 'this' pointer inside the derived class.

I'm very curious about why 'this' pointer is allowed to polymorphism to its private parent, however, a pointer outside of the class is not.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual void say() const = 0;
    virtual void who()
    {
        std::cout << "Shape" << std::endl;
    }
    void whoAmI() {
        this->who();
    }
};

class Squire : private Shape
{
public:
    virtual void say() const
    {
        std::cout << "Squire" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void doSay()
    {
        // why this pointer to Shape type is allowed in class?
        privateSay(this);
    }
    
private:
    void privateSay(Shape* s)
    {
        s->say();
    }
};

void say(Shape* s)
{
    s->say();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    
    Squire* s = new Squire();
    // allowed
    s->doSay();
    
    // not allowd, compile errors
    // Cannot cast 'Squire' to its private base class 'Shape'
    say(s);
    
    return 0;
}
```

=========

Edit to clarify.
Thanks for all the answers.
To clarify my question, I think if C++ allows this behavior, mybe it violates the **encapsulation** a little.

A clearer case:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    void baseFunc() const
    {
        std::cout << "baseFunc" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Worker
{
public:
    Worker(Base *pBase)
    {
        base_ = pBase;
    }
    
    void breakFunc() const
    {
        base_->baseFunc();
    }
private:
    Base *base_;
};

class Derived : private Base
{
public:
    void init()
    {
        worker_ = new Worker(this);
    }
    
    Worker* getWorker()
    {
        return worker_;
    }

private:
    Worker *worker_;
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    derived.init();
    
    
    Worker *worker = derived.getWorker();
    worker->breakFunc();
}
```

The object of Base class only exisits in the object of Derived class as the parent object part, however, the Derived class inheritents Base class **privately**, which means the object of the Derived class **has-an** object of the Base class, **privately**.

The code above violates the **encapsulation** rule of the Derived class, however, even no warnning is given during compilation.

In my opinion, an explicit cast should be used under the circumstances，or an warning should be given during compilation.

Comment: Private inheritance is less of the usual is-a relationship, and more a variant of composition. So `Squire` isn't really a `Shape`, but rather contains a `Shape`.

Comment: And why do you have private inheritance? What problem is that supposed to solve? If you ask this question just out of curiosity then that's fine, but please state so. Otherwise please ask about the actual underlying problem you try to solve directly instead.

Comment: `private` is all about context, i.e. whether inside or outside of the class. With that in mind, I don't understand why the behaviour surprises you. What would you expect to happen instead?

Comment: `private` visibility means the information this applies to is only available in the context of the class. In this case the information it applies to is "`Shape` is a base class of `Squire`". You can access this kind of info inside `Squire`, but nowhere else.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt instead of asking rhetorical question a person who seems not to understand the point of "all about context", you could just state, that an inherited class *always* knows its base classes, so it is possible to do `static_cast` to its base within the scope of its methods.

Comment: In `main()`,  `s` is defined (and initialised) so it points at an instance of `Squire`  or to an instance of a class derived from `Squire`.   `Squire` has a `public` member function named `doSay()` so `s->doSay()` is valid.  `say(s)` fails because `main()` is neither a member nor a `friend` of `Squire`, so does not have access to the `private` base named `Shape` which (among other things) means it is not permitted to convert a `Squire *` to a `Shape *`.  All member functions of `Squire` have access to all private members and bases of that class, so can convert a `Squire *` to a `Shape *`.

Comment: In the context of the Squire class, it is aware that it inherits from Shape class, and it's privates are accessible to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asked here is *why a base class is accessible when privately inherited*.
The answer is rather simple: *Because base classes are always visible to  inherited regardless of the type of inheritance*.

You can `static_cast` to a base class when the base is visible within the context.

```
class base
{
};

class inherited : base
{
public:

void foo()
{
    // works, base is visible within the method.
    auto pBase = static_cast<base*>(this);
}
};

int main() {
    inherited i{};
    // auto pBase = static_cast<base*>(&i); // won't compile, base is not visible
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Private inheritance means that both `public` and `protected` symbols from the base class become `private` symbols of the derived class. `private` symbols of the base class are inaccessible to the derived class. With exception of private virtual methods which can still be overridden.

`this` pointers, or in general `Class* ptr` used inside the class, can access private fields of the class.

Since the symbol `Shape::say` is public in `Shape`, it becomes private in `Squire`(BTW Did you mean Square?). This prevents its usage by public but not by `this`. Due to rules of virtuals, this "privatizes" the whole chain of overridden methods.

```cpp
void Squire::privateSay(Shape* s)
{
    // Works because `Shape::say` is a public symbol of Shape -> private symbol of Squire and `this` can access private symbols.
    s->say();
}
```

```cpp
void say(Shape* s)
{
    // Shape::say is a private symbol, obviously cannot be called.
    s->say();
}
```

If there existed private `Shape::foo()` method, it would not be accessible even through `this` in any of the `Squire`'s methods.

Comment: You're mentioning members a lot in your answer. However it's not the visibility of the members of that's an issue here. The issue is that the cast from `Squire*` to `Squire*` is only available inside `Squire`( ; to me the effect on member visiblility is a corrolary of this). In fact you'd get the exact same issue, if you don't access any members of `Shape` inside `::say` (`void say(Shape*){}`)